# How to avoid static shocks on equipment

Tags: equipment, static

Instead of grounding myself with a bracelet, can I wear rubber gloves? Will this prevent any equipment I touch from getting shocked?

Comment: How certain are you that the rubber can't carry a charge?

Comment: Maybe if they are nice thick gloves.  But dude, why not just ground yourself?

Comment: The rubber gloves might help in picking up a charge ;-)

Comment: I know that rubber shoes do!

Comment: Rubber will make things worse. Rubber is isolating, so able to build up a charge (as it doesn't dissipate).

Comment: There are wireless bracelets which depend on Corona ionization. Of course they don't work but it is a more comforting idea than the rubber gloves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to prevent static shocks is not to try to prevent static discharge, but to ensure safe discharge. Otherwise the charge will just continue to build up until it finds some (unwanted) way of discharging.

Many labs ensure this by using shoes with conductive soles, and a floor that conducts to ground (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a healthy relative humidity in your workspace will eliminate the issue. In mid-winter in New Hampshire, a consumer-grade humidifier keeps our 900+ sq-ft space at 33% RH or more, and I haven't zapped a part yet.